# What are the reasons behind naming the "community chest" and "chance" cards in Monopoly?

Tags: monopoly, history

Why are the cards called so?

Are there any plausible reasons as why they are included in the game of monopoly?  Does their naming have anything to do with real-world namings?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Community Chest is named from the original Atlantic City version of Monopoly.

In Atlantic City, the [Community Chest](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&q=atlantic+city+community+chest&oq=atlantic+city+community+chest&gs_l=serp.3...263563.268328.0.268477.29.17.0.0.0.0.329.1398.0j1j1j3.5.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..24.5.1398._6CVEgraqlU) was a welfare organisation.  Therefore, [Community Chest](http://monopoly.wikia.com/wiki/Community_Chest) cards are more likely than not to give money.

On the other hand, [Chance](http://monopoly.wikia.com/wiki/Chance) cards are more likely to move you to a random 'chance' location.

Comment: Atlantic City is also primarily known for its casinos and gambling, hence 'Chance' being thematic.

Comment: @Affe: The first Casino in Atlantic City dates from only 1974; Monopoly has antecedents dating back to 1903, and was published in its current standard form in 1935., almost 40 years earlier.

Comment: @Forget I was ever here :There were casinos in Atlantic city in the 1920s, during prohibition. "Racetrack gambling was legalized again in 1939, but despite the fact that gambling was illegal in the state until then illegal casino and bookmaking operations, slot machines, and numbers rackets abounded in Atlantic City." Reference : «The Complete History of Gambling in Atlantic City», https://www.njonlinegambling.com/atlantic-city-history/